# Multiple ExpansionTile with multiple ListTile, how to do a second one

Tags: flutter, dart

This question might sound dumb, but I am trying to make a list of Expandable list items which in turn have a list of items inside. I have come this far but I am unable to make it a show a second one WITHOUT USING INDEX.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExerciseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExerciseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExerciseScreen> createState() => _ExerciseScreenState();
}

class _ExerciseScreenState extends State<ExerciseScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Table of Contents CEFR'),
      ),
      
      body: ListView(
        children: const [
          ExpansionTile(
            leading: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 182, 91),
                child: Text(
                  'A1',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              'To be: is, am, are',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Text('A1'),
                ),
                title: Text('Affirmative ideas'),
                subtitle: Text('Singular and plural subjects'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Text('A1'),
                ),
                title: Text('Are: plural verb'),
                subtitle: Text('Positive ideas using plural subjects'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Text('A1'),
                ),
                title: Text('Is : singular verb'),
                subtitle: Text('Positive ideas using singular subjects'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Text('A1'),
                ),
                title: Text('Questions'),
                subtitle: Text('Interrogative ideas - subject/verb/switch '),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Text('A1'),
                ),
                title: Text('Questions'),
                subtitle: Text('Closed questions (yes/no)'),
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
          
        ],
        
      ),
      
    );
    
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem with just adding a second **ExpansionTile** to your list? Like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExerciseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExerciseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExerciseScreen> createState() => _ExerciseScreenState();
}

class _ExerciseScreenState extends State<ExerciseScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Table of Contents CEFR'),
      ),
      
      body: ListView(
        children: const [
          ExpansionTile(...),
          ExpansionTile(...),
        ],
        
      ),
      
    );
    
  }
}
```

On my side it shows both **ExpansionTile**s correctly:

[image]

Comment: That is waht I needed, I appreciatte your help. As silly as it might look. I could not figured it out before.